# Size of std::array in class template depending on template parameter

Tags: c++, c++11, templates

I have a the following class template

```
template<int N>
constexpr int arraySize() { return arraySize<N-1>() + N; }

template<>
constexpr int arraySize<0>() { return 0; }

template<int C>
class MyClass {
    public:
    std::array<int, arraySize<C>()> arr;
};

int main() {

    MyClass<3> cls;
    std::cout << cls.arr.size() << std::endl;    // Output: 6
}
```

Everything works but I would like to have `calculateArraySize<N>()` as a member function. I've tried the following:

```
template<int C>
class MyClass {
    public:

    static constexpr int arraySize();
    std::array<int, MyClass<C>::arraySize()> arr;
};

template<int C>
constexpr int MyClass<C>::arraySize(){ return MyClass<C-1>::arraySize() + C; }

template<>
constexpr int MyClass<0>::arraySize() { return 0; }
```

Results in the following error:

> fatal error: recursive template instantiation exceeded maximum
>         depth of 1024
>       std::array::arraySize()> arr;

```
template<int C>
class MyClass {
    public:

    template<int N>
    static constexpr int arraySize();
    std::array<int, MyClass::arraySize<C>()> arr;
};

template<int C>
template<int N>
constexpr int MyClass<C>::arraySize(){ return MyClass::arraySize<N-1>() + N-1; }

template<int C>
template<>
constexpr int MyClass<C>::arraySize<0>() { return 0; }
```

Gives the following error:

> tmp.cc:19:27: error: cannot specialize (with 'template<>') a member of an
>         unspecialized template
>   constexpr int MyClass::arraySize<0>() { return 0; }

Is it possible to achieve the desired behaviour? Solutions using C++14/C++17 features (I guess it should be possible usinn if-constexpr) are welcomed but won't solve my particular problem since only C++11 is available.

Comment: Tip : The sum of the first `N` natural numbers (so `1+2+3+...+N`) is `N*(N+1)/2`.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux yep, I know, thank you. My question is not only about this particular case, it's more like a simple example.

Comment: Then it's not clear to me what you are asking. If the problem is that you are exceeding the maximum depth, then the first solution is to reduce the recursion depth. Are you asking how to specialize a member function?

Comment: You cannot specialize a member function in C++, without specializing the whole class.

Comment: The second error idicates this. Is are any workaround?

Comment: @datell You can delegate to a helper struct and specialize that helper struct instead.

Comment: @ArnavBorborah, this is not technically correct. You certainly **can** specialize member function of the class, but on it's own template arguments (provided it is a template in itself).

Comment: @SergeyA You are correct, I just wasn't being specific enough.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can move the function into the class and the specialize the entire class for the base case.  That looks like:

```
template<int C>
class MyClass {
    public:

    static constexpr int arraySize(){ return MyClass<C-1>::arraySize() + C; }
    std::array<int, MyClass<C>::arraySize()> arr;
};

template<>
class MyClass<0> {
    public:
    static constexpr int arraySize(){ return 0; }
};

int main() {
    MyClass<3> cls;
    std::cout << cls.arr.size() << std::endl;    // Output: 6
}
```

[Live Example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d0901fdb3e5f6553)

Comment: @datell, keep in mind, this specialization does not inherit anything from template. I.e, if your template class `MyClass<C>`, for example, had a member `int blah`, specialization `MyClass<C>` as written would not have this member.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use a member variable instead of a member function.

```
template <int C>
class MyClass {
   public:

      static constexpr int array_size = MyClass<C-1>::array_size + C;
      std::array<int, array_size> arr;
};

template <>
class MyClass<0> {
   public:
       static constexpr int array_size = 0;
};
```